# How to duplicate regex search result within one line?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I have a csv table following the scheme:

```
    "text1","text2",3
    "text5","text?",5
    "baa","foo",99
    ...
```

Which I need to transform to:

```
    "text1","text2","-text2-",3
    "text5","text?","-text?-",5
    "baa","foo","-foo-",99
    ...
```

I'm sorry but I have no idea how to duplicate a part of a line using a regex.
I'm using VS Code find-replace engine.
How could I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/gokPCg/1).

Find: `^(\s*"[^"]*?","([^"]*?)",)`

Replace: `$1"-$2-",`

Group 1: the first two values in each line, like `"text1","text2",`

Group 2: just the inner second value, like `text2`

Replace: Use Group 1 and then replicate Group 2 with surrounding `"-Group2-"`

Make sure you have this in your settings.json:

```
"search.usePCRE2": true,
```

Answer (score 0):

"text1","text2",3

"text5","text?",5

Find the matched word group1, group2, group3. Match A-Za-z0-9 and "?" characters. I am not sure how long the last data number that I set the number 1~3 digital numbers. You can adjust to your condition easier.

```
("[\w?]+"),"([\w?]+)",(\d{1,3})
```

Replace with regex as following

```
$1,"$2","-$2-",$3
```

The results should be as following

"text1","text2","-text2-",3

"text5","text?","-text?-",5

Never mind asking questions to me.